# AngularJS, Add Rows

Tags: angularjs

Morning,

We are trying to implement this add row [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VJSO588pXYBc72mC0sfg?p=preview), it seems to work however our input data seems to repeat. Does anyone know of a solution to add a unique id to preview duplicated fields ?

Here is our current [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/lwne6T2BenwSKpbszLwd?p=preview) and [LIVE](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/lwne6T2BenwSKpbszLwd/#/warranty/1/visual_details) example.

```
$scope.addRow = function(){
  var row = {};
  $scope.productdata.push(row);
};
$scope.removeRow = function(index){
  $scope.productdata.splice(index, 1);
};
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should provide a smaller plunkr. Yours is huge, and doesn't have an "Add Row" button.

Comment: We've re-saved and the 'Add Row' button is definitely there.

Comment: please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/68XWqQfx1JNCG0lxjiTK?p=preview

Comment: I can see this working but unfortunately its breaking the radio button selects, your only able to select or of each option instead of been able to select one each row.

Comment: @rawco_de plese see here http://plnkr.co/edit/68XWqQfx1JNCG0lxjiTK?p=preview

Comment: @sylwester We are almost there with this, I can see that you've switched the radio buttons to check-boxes but this dosn't allow us to only select one option per row, your previous plnkr was closer but you could only select three options in the entire selection instead. i've attached another image so you can see what I mean. Thank you once again for all your hard work and time.

Comment: @rawco_de please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/qvI86pHU5zuwf8ZmdGQ7?p=preview

Comment: @sylwester the json product data at the bottom is they any way to add this to formdata like the other pages ? so when the user click the next and previous pages the data stores within the factory. Apart from this its working perfectly. I can clearly see where I was going wrong.

Comment: @rawco_de http://plnkr.co/edit/VzSrB8vYS0n7uZEgKSUT?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

*$scope.formData* you have is not an array, but just one object. All your rows are bound to that object and hence all of them reference the same data.

The reason you get a new row added is because your ng-repeat is bound to *$scope.productData* and you add extra record in it. You should bind your form elements to the properties in the row object that you create

a simple example is :

### In your template

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products">
    <input type="text" ng-model="product.title">
</div>
```

### In your controller

```
$scope.addProduct = function(){
    var product = {};
    $scope.productData.add(product);
}
```

You'd then always only work with the productData array and bind your model to them.
Even in your backend calls, you'd use productData instead of your formData.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this within our Plunlr and the 'Add Row' feature stopped working altogether.

Comment: Make sure that your variables and functions are named properly. For example your method is named addRow() whereas my example had addProduct(). Did you update it in your template as well?

Comment: BTW, your problem is not in the addRow() method. This is perfectly valid. It is where you bind your variables in your template using ng-model. Bind your form elements to the array elements in the array you are iterating over in your template using ng-repeat, i.e. productdata. 

So instead of 

ng-model="formData['N/A '+product.WarrantyTestID]"

you'd have

ng-model = "product[<your-key-here>]"

Answer (score 0):

**U can use a filter :** This will return Unique rows only

```
app.filter('unique', function () {

return function (items, filterOn) {

    if (filterOn === false) {
        return items;
    }

    if ((filterOn || angular.isUndefined(filterOn)) && angular.isArray(items)) {
        var hashCheck = {}, newItems = [];

        var extractValueToCompare = function (item) {
            if (angular.isObject(item) && angular.isString(filterOn)) {
                return item[filterOn];
            } else {
                return item;
            }
        };

        angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
            var valueToCheck, isDuplicate = false;

            for (var i = 0; i < newItems.length; i++) {
                if (angular.equals(extractValueToCompare(newItems[i]), extractValueToCompare(item))) {
                    isDuplicate = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!isDuplicate) {
                newItems.push(item);
            }

        });
        items = newItems;
    }
    return items;
};
```

});

Comment: how would I go around implementing this to what we have already done ?

Comment: 1. add above code to a js file and include in your index.html 2. In your HTML page where u r doing ng-repeat="row in rows"... there use filter "UNIQUE" like this : ng-repeat="row in rows | unique:'KEY'

Comment: Something like this <tbody ng-repeat="warrant in warranty | unique : 'Model' ">

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why this is happening is that the addRow() function is just pushing an empty son object into the $scope.productdata array, whereas all input fields are bound to $scope.formData[product.WarrantyTestDescription]. I think you mean to bind the input fields to the properties of the product object.